# How to make private repository public using the command line interface?

Tags: github, github-cli

I am submitting a task to a bot. I can't see the settings tab. Therefore, I wanted to use command line to execute the command .

How can I make my private repository public using the git bash command line?

Comment: Anyway, this question is not about code/development so *StackOverflow* is not the place for it, have you considered porting the question to *SuperUser* or any other of the network's websites?

Comment: No, I didn't know about these websites

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the [GitHub Cli](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit):

```
 gh repo edit --visibility public
```

Answer (score 0):

Using git command I don't think it's possible. You can use GitHub cli repo edit command : https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit or you can directly use GitHub API'S to accomplish this.